# Is it possible to connect to an Azure Sql Database from Sql Server Management Studio with service principal/app registration?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-sql-server, azure-service-principal

I have configured my sql server with an Azure Active Directory admin that is a service principal (app registration). Is it possible to use clientid/secret to connect from Sql Management Studio?

I have tried Azure Active Directory - password authentication but client id and secret did not work.

It works just fine from my C# code with the same id and secret.

Comment: Most likely you can't. Authenticating a service principal is different from a user, and only the password authentication method could potentially work if the SSMS developers made it detect when a client id is used instead of a username. Based on your test, they probably haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @junnas in the comment section we cannot connect to  Azure SQL database with Service Principal in SSMS.

Please check this  [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-49-does-azure-sql-database-support-azure-active/ba-p/369055)

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to support it?

Answer (score 2):

SSMS 19 allows connecting to SQL Server using a Service Principal

[image: Connecting to SQL Server via Service Principal]